# Using re2 in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, re2

I need to use re2 in python3. The installation worked fine but when I import it I receive this error:

```
>>> import re2 as re
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "re2.pyx", line 1, in init re2 (src/re2.cpp:13681)
NameError: basestring
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: I have just installed build-essential libre2-dev form aptitude and then re2 through pip!

Answer (score 12):

The version released to PyPI is not Python 3 compatible; `basestring` only exists in Python 2. This will not be the only problem, fixing a text-focused project to fit the Python 3 all-text-is-Unicode view is not trivial.

It appears the specific project is unmaintained; others [have already reported the problem](https://github.com/axiak/pyre2/issues/34), and people have pointed to a different fork: https://github.com/andreasvc/pyre2.

You can install that project directly from GitHub:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/andreasvc/pyre2.git
```

Note that you'll need to install Cython first for that project to compile; unlike the other fork the generated C++ file (from the `re2.pyx` file) is not checked in. Just run `pip install Cython`.

You could also look at alternatives; perhaps the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) would fit your requirements as well. `regex` is a drop-in replacement for `re` with additional features, like vastly improved Unicode support.

Comment: regex module is 10X slower so nobody want to use it. re2 should be part of Python. Still not in for Python 3.7.2 I hope it will be for Python 3.8 and after!

Comment: Have folks tried import cffi_re2 as re how does it compare to pyre2 in term of speed ?

Comment: Issue with Python 3.7 import error: /dev/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/re2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK3re23RE25MatchERKNS_11StringPieceEmmNS0_6AnchorEPS1_i

Comment: recompile re2 no luck 
(venv) [ec2-user@ip-172-29-0-54 site-packages]$ ldd re2.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc92f5c000)
    libre2.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libre2.so.0 (0x00007f8de0668000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8de02e2000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8ddffe0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8ddfdca000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8ddfbad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8ddf7e0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a3bf47f000)

Comment: Sorry, I have no answers for you here. Sounds like a library version mismatch.